# Lighting parameters to render interior architectural scene?

Tags: light

I'm rendering some indoor architecture, and I'm having trouble with the texture color, because it changes a lot depending on the HDRI I use. I would like to know what the setup of lights is recommended for the so that the textures do not change color as much.

Comment: What do you mean by "the colors change a lot depending on the lighting"? That's sort of what they're supposed to do. Are you asking how to get even lighting?

Comment: the problem is that, for example, if an oak is of a certain color in the texture image, must be the same color / tone in the render appearance changes depending on the hdr image of background I use. 

I use hdr in blender cycles by improving render times and make renders cleaner, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to go for a specific texture color tone, try setting your HDR image to a single one and then adjust the colors of your textures manually (nodes) while keeping a look on the realtime cycles viewport render. If you change the HDR of course you have to redo the process.

Another way would be to be sure your original texture's color has not been affected by colored light before you loaded it into blender.(e.g you took a photo of of your oak furniture wood while having a light turned on that has a yellowish tone and used the image as a texture, resulting in a weird appearance in your render).